# VLC freezes last frame from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, video, vlc-media-player, video-playback

Suppose I play a video file via VLC from the Windows command line. Are there command line parameters which cause VLC to stop at the last frame and just display it as a fixed image instead of closing the video completely? Is there any other Windows video player which can do this starting from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried but i achieved upto the point of pausing a vedio and getting a snapshot of it whithout closing the vedio and then resuming it. Here is what i have done:

```
c:\prog~1\vlc\VLC>vlc -I rc -vvv "address of vedio file to open"
```

This will open up rc interface and also the vedio in direct 3d desktop mode.
At RC interface window type `help` to get list of commands. I have written `pause` to pause the vedio and `snapshot` to get the snap of the particular frame.